# Can't set ttl duration in bloodhound

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

i'm using bootstrap typeahead v0.11.1 but i'm wondering if i can set an other value for ttl (the default one is 1 day )

this is my code :

```js
var taxes = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    prefetch: {
        url :'/taxes.json'
        ttl : 5000
    },
    remote: {
        url: '/source.php?query=%QUERY',
        filter: function (taxes) {

            // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
            return $.map(taxes, function (movie) {
               
                return {
                    val: movie.val,
                    name: movie.name,
                    type: movie.type

                };
            });
        },
        wildcard : '%QUERY'
    }
});

taxes.initialize();

$('#pretva_name').typeahead({ highlight:false,
    hint: false,
    offset: false,
    minLength:2}, {

    display: 'name',


    source: taxes.ttAdapter(),



});
```

The remote option is working just fine but the prefetched source is always the same